# Oracle equivalent staement for the given MySql statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Can somebody tell me the equivalent oracle statement for the given mySql statement:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/city?user=root&password=root");
```

Comment: Have you tried searching the JDBC connection url for Oracle before asking?

Comment: Nopes I am completely new to this.

Comment: Well, now you know what to do. Do the respective research.

Comment: Don't you mind using the docs? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

Comment: Where is the `mySql statement`?

Answer (score 3):

```
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection = 
            DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MySID","username","password");
```

If you use `:` (`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MySID`) - after that, the SID name is expected. 
If you use `/` (`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/MySERVICE`) - the service name is expected

More here: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Comment: With modern (JDBC 4.0 and newer) JDBC drivers `Class.forName(...)` is no longer necessary.